Azure Managed Identity obtained JWT token does not work with HotChocolate Authorization
I have a simple GraphQL implementation using HotChocolate v13 where several resolvers are protected by Authorize HotChocolate implementation and as soon as a JWT token is passed for an Azure AD user, it works fine.
Now I have a function that needs to invoke a query from the GraphQL endpoint using a JWT obtained by using the function Managed Identity resulting in a response like the one below:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The current user is not authorized to access this resource.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "me"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "AUTH_NOT_AUTHORIZED"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Same GraphQL api has other regular Controllers but protected by asp.net Core [Authorize] attribute and invoking them with the Managed Identity JWT token works fine.
Why is that happening? meaning JWT obtained via Managed Identity approach does not work with HotChocolate GraphQL?

To use the authorization functionality, you must use the [Authorize] attribute from the HotChocolate namespace, not the one from the Microsoft namespace. Additionally, you need to call AddAuthorization on the schema builder.

all that is in place, and still having the issue
